# Inviting X number of friends to use a Facebook App

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

We're scoping out an app that will live within a microsite. We'll be using FB Connect to connect to the user's FB info. What we want to do, is at the end, share the microsite with up to 25 friends.

i looked at the legacy code, but don't even think it was possible then.

We're building this in dotNet MVC 3. I'm not on the app dev team, but helping looking for answers.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can send message to your friends using send pop up from Graph API:

here is code you need in body part of page

```
<div id="fb-root">  </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js"></script>
<div class="footer">
<br />
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.init({
        appId: '<%=lAppId %>',
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
    });

</script>
</div>
```

Here is Java Script function you need to call in order to open send popup (window which will allow you to select friends to send message)

```
function invite() {
    var lLinkToPublish=GeAppUrl();
    var lTextToPublish=GetPublishText();
    var lTitleText=GetInvitationTitle();
   FB.ui({
          method: 'send',
          name: lTitleText,
          display: 'popup',
          description: lTextToPublish,
          link: lLinkToPublish ,
          });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write explicit code to do that and maintain the number of connections you have by yourself in the database.

Comment: That's what we've been thinking too. 

We've been thinking of something that pulls all my friends and their profile pic, and a method to search, with a radio button as a selection method.

Is it possible to directly message friends, or would it be wall posts only?

Comment: You can't send facebook message to your friends programmatic from api. That permission was revoked by facebook due to abuse.

Comment: But, you can still send emails to friends... or pop open a dialog for the user to send messages.